# How to implement multi Language support in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, multilingual, google-translation-api

I'm developing a large-scale application with React and node, which has a form builder, form assigning to user functionality, etc.
I need to add multi-language support for this application. Since there are large amounts of hardcode text and some user-generated text, How can I implement the functionality so it doesn't affect performance?
I referred [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) library, which can be used for handling transition.

Also, I need to translate the values into multiple languages programmatically with the help of any online translation API ( probably Google Translate API if it is a good choice )

How can approach this issue?

Comment: Hi, Are you using SSR? If so, which one?

Comment: I will tell you that Google Translate is NOT a good choice.  (I tried it) It produces lots of indecipherable translations.

Comment: @Serafim no i not using SSR.

Comment: @ControlAltDel , what is the best choice for translations, i do have a quite large number of text

Comment: I18n is the best choice. You'll probably want to hire a translator. There might be a sophisticated translation softward somewhere, but I think you'd have to pay for that too.

Comment: @dextey then reaction-i18next is a good choice (in terms of bundle size, popularity and community support)

Comment: But these libraries doesn't provide an option to translate the actual values, we our self need to provide the translated values.
I need a method to translate the text automated rather than using a translator

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the fuse react 4.0+ template as a reference. You can find there multi langauge support using `react-i18next`.
You can check directly in [this url](https://github.com/EliteDevSolution/Fuse-React-v4.0.0-skeleton-Template/tree/master/src/app/fuse-configs/navigation-i18n).